# SQLite sort COLLATE LOCALIZED doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database created with SQLite Database Browser. Database contains some Turkish specific letters. To sort them alphabetically i tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

I am using `SQLiteAssetHelper`

What may be wrong?

```
public Cursor getAuthors() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.setLocale(new Locale("tr","TR"));


    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = { "_id", "name", "surname", "photoName" };
    String sqlTables = "authors";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null,
            "name,surname COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

    c.moveToFirst();

    return c;

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `SQLiteQueryBuilder` is causing some problem when composing the query? You don't really need it anyway, you could just call `db.query(sqlTables, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, "name,surname COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");` instead.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. Still doesn't work

Comment: Does your create table statement define the column as being collated? `CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name TEXT COLLATE LOCALIZED, ... )`

Comment: sqlite doesnt support localization afaik..

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Android's does. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: @Karakuri oh okie i dint know abt this, then may be sqlite alone doesnt support this..

Comment: @Karakuri No, i create tables with SQLite Database Browser, now i edited the database with another editor and it works fine, thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
"name,surname COLLATE LOCALIZED"
```

sorts the `name` column with the default collation and the `surname` column with the localized collation.

To sort both columns with the localized collation, you have to specify the collation for both:

```
"name COLLATE LOCALIZED, surname COLLATE LOCALIZED"
```